# How can I delete NodeJS in ubuntu 20.4?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I've tried various ways to clear this version of Node.js. But in the end, this version is not deleted!

I tried several methods like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786015/how-to-remove-nodejs-from-ubuntu-16-04)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try the following steps

- `npm cache clean -f`
- `npm install -g n`
- `sudo n [version]`

the `version` that you want

Comment: My problem solved but how to change the version to this version when i use node -v again have nodejs nightly !

Comment: You can use this `nvm alias default [version]`. **version** that you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following commands in your terminal.

- `sudo apt-get remove nodejs`
- `sudo apt-get purge nodejs`
- `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Answer (score 1):

For some reason or another `node` was installed twice on my Ubuntu 20:

```
/usr/bin/node       # Installed by apt
/usr/bin/nodejs     -> /usr/bin/node
/usr/local/bin/node # Nightly
```

I solved the problem by:

```sh
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/node && sudo ln -s /usr/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
```

Resulting in

```
/usr/bin/node       # Installed by apt
/usr/bin/nodejs     -> /usr/bin/node
/usr/local/bin/node -> /usr/bin/node
```

Solved my troubles with `gulp-sass`.